# Table of Contents for set of PDF files

Tags: table-of-contents, pdfpages

How to make Table of Contents for a set of PDF files?

Here's my code!

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[pdfauthor={<somename>},pdftitle={<sometitle>},pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in,bottom=0.75in,top=0.75in]{geometry}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\fancyhead[L]{X Y Z}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\clearpage
\phantomsection
\includepdfset{pages=-,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{fancy}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{SAMPLE PDF 1\\ \textit{description}}
\includepdf[pages=-]{template1.pdf}

\clearpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{SAMPLE PDF 2\\ \textit{description}}
\includepdf[pages=-]{template2.pdf}

\clearpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{SAMPLE PDF 3\\ \textit{description}}
\includepdf[pages=-]{template3.pdf}

\clearpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{SAMPLE PDF 4\\ \textit{description}}
\includepdf[pages=-]{template4.pdf}

\clearpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{SAMPLE PDF 5\\ \textit{description}}
\includepdf[pages=-]{template5.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Here's the output.

[image]

My problem is that the page number is not aligned with the title, it is aligned with the description. Also I'd like to put dots.

My desired output looks like this:[image]

Comment: Please don't use an external reference for your question. Linking to it is ok if you really want to, but try to make the question self-contained, so that answerers don't need to work simply to understand the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is adapted from some code I wrote once for a similar purpose. You simply call the macro `\insertmydocument` instead of `\includepdf`.

For the description, it turns out `tocloft` can handle the typesetting of a "chapter precis" in toc, in text or both. It seems to be exactly what you are looking for.

```
%The default settings should add dots, but for whatever reason it doesn't. This fixes it.
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotsfill{\cftchapdotsep}}

\newcommand{\insertmydocument}[4]%
           { % Syntax: \insertmydocument{Toc level}{Title}{Subtitle}{File}
             % Requires: tocloft hyperref pdfpages
             \newpage
             \phantomsection
             \cftaddtitleline{toc}{#1}{#2}{\thepage}
             \cftchapterprecistoc{#3}
             \includepdf[pages=-]{#4}
           }
```

I suggest you add `colorlink` to the `hyperref` options, so that the links are colored instead of boxed. This will get rid of the big box on the first line.

### Full example

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}


\newcommand{\insertmydocument}[4]%
           { % Syntax: \insertmydocument{Toc level}{Title}{Subtitle}{File}
             % Requires: tocloft hyperref pdfpages
             \newpage
             \phantomsection
             \cftaddtitleline{toc}{#1}{#2}{\thepage}
             \cftchapterprecistoc{#3}
            \includepdf[pages=-]{#4}
           }


\begin{document}


\tableofcontents

\chapter{A regular chapter}

\insertmydocument{chapter}{A pdf}{Description}{document.pdf}

\chapter{Another chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ScareCrow : I hadn't understood the layout you were after. I edited my answer.

Comment: @ T.Verron i want a layout like this: http://i.imgur.com/7tmSrId.png?1. im a newbie i want to try your code but i dont know where to put your codes in my codes. can you give me an example of a whole code?

Comment: @ScareCrow: Added the full code for the picture, you might need to change the name of the inserted pdf of course.

Answer (score 8):

for each PDF you can use the option `addtotoc` from `pdfpages`:

```
\includepdf[addtotoc={1,chapter,0,SAMPLE PDF 1,chap:samplepdfone}]{template1.pdf}
```