# Included PDF should appear as bookmark

Tags: hyperref, pdfpages, tocloft, bookmarks

I modified [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112064/101831) answer to include PDFs in my file.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}


\newcommand{\insertmydocument}[4]%
           { % Syntax: \insertmydocument{Toc level}{Title}{File}
             % Requires: tocloft hyperref pdfpages
             \newpage
             \phantomsection
             \cftaddtitleline{toc}{#1}{#2}{\thepage}
            \includepdf[pages=-]{#3}
           }


\begin{document}


\tableofcontents

\chapter{A regular chapter}

\insertmydocument{chapter}{A pdf}{document}

\chapter{Another chapter}

\end{document}
```

**Problem**

The included PDF doesn't appear in the bookmark section of my pdf viewer.

[image]

Can somebody explain me why and how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\cftaddtitleline` doesn't create bookmarks.

You can add them e.g. with bookmark:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\newcommand{\insertmydocument}[4]%
           { % Syntax: \insertmydocument{Toc level}{Title}{File}
             % Requires: tocloft hyperref pdfpages
             \newpage
             \phantomsection
             \bookmark[level=chapter,dest=\csname @currentHref\endcsname]{#2}%
             \cftaddtitleline{toc}{#1}{#2}{\thepage}
            \includepdf[pages=-]{#3}
           }


\begin{document}


\tableofcontents

\chapter{A regular chapter}

\insertmydocument{chapter}{A pdf}{example-image}

\chapter{Another chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great solution! In my file I changed `level=chapter` to `level=#1` so that the bookmarks have the same structure (chapter, section, subsection...) like the document.